# Snackbar div persisting in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, snackbar

I am using snackbarjs to show alert messages. But sometimes, the remnant div of snackbar ramains after the snackbar disappears. Any fix to this is appreciated. Here, I spam clicked my button that activates a snackbar so you guys can see where im having trouble with.
It also block elements behind it.

[image]